# How to get facebook graphi api acess tokens programatically

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get data from public pages of facebook using graph api.
This requires acess tokens.But I want to automate the process such that I get the data after ever day but the tokens expire after some time. Is there any method to get the acess tokens programatically to automate this thing ?
Also why it acess tokens are required for public pages ?

Answer (score 1):

The only Token you get without user interaction is an App Access Token. It´s basically "App-ID|App-Secret" (with a pipe sign). This works as long as the Page is not restricted by age or location. In that case, you would need to use a User or Page Token, because Facebook can´t identify a User (and his age or location) with an App Token.

You can also use an Extended Page Token, which is valid forever. But you have to be Admin of the Page for that one.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

If you want to know why Tokens are needed, you need to ask Facebook.